# Clarification on the Nielsen-Schreier Theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I am a new student of Geometric Group theory, and my professor walked us through a proof of the Nielsen-Schreier Theorem that uses the fact that a group that acts freely on a tree must be free. Our development of the theory only applies to finitely generated groups, however, and I was wondering the following. Does the Nielsen-Schreier theorem apply to free groups of infinite rank as well?

Comment: There is no fundamental difference between the finitely generated and general case, apart from the usage of (some form of) the Axiom of Choice, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403284/nielsen-schreier-and-the-axiom-of-choice). How did your proof used finite generation?

Comment: Earlier in the course the development of our theory used the fact that Cayley graphs of finitely generated groups are locally finite (we follow Groups Graphs and Trees by John Meier roughly). Perhaps we don't need this assumption, but I wasn't quite sure. I had seen proofs of Nielsen-Schreier using Algebraic Topology but I'm not familiar enough to understand if those proofs apply to free groups of arbitrary rank. Thank you!

Comment: Once you accept the axiom of choice, any reasonable proof that works for finitely-generated groups, will also work in general. In particular, local finiteness is irrelevant, in fact, I do not see how it can be used (besides helping you to produce a maximal tree in the given graph, which is what AC is for).